# Concatenate string literal with another string

Tags: string, concatenation, rust

Is there some reason why I cannot concatenate a string literal with a string variable? The following code:

```
fn main() {
    let x = ~"abcd";
    io::println("Message: " + x);
}
```

gives this error:

```
test2.rs:3:16: 3:31 error: binary operation + cannot be applied to type `&'static str`
test2.rs:3     io::println("Message: " + x);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I guess this is a pretty basic and very common pattern, and usage of `fmt!` in such cases only brings unnecessary clutter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default string literals have static lifetime, and it is not possible to concatenate unique and static vectors. Using unique literal string helped:

```
fn main() {
    let x = ~"abcd";
    io::println(~"Message: " + x);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

With the latest version of Rust (0.11), the tilde (`~`) operator is deprecated.

Here's an example of how to fix it with version 0.11:

```
let mut foo = "bar".to_string();
foo = foo + "foo";
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how to apply your answer to the question.  Could you show how to implement his actual abcd and Message example?

Comment: Why is it that String can be concatenated with &str, but not 2 Strings?

Answer (score 2):

Just to addon to the above answer, as long as the right most string is of the type ~str then you can add any kind of string to it.

```
let x = ~"Hello" + @" " + &"World" + "!";
```