# How to concatenate static strings in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to concatenate static strings and string literals to build another static string. The following is the best I could come up with, but it doesn't work:

```
const DESCRIPTION: &'static str = "my program";
const VERSION: &'static str = env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION");
const VERSION_STRING: &'static str = concat!(DESCRIPTION, " v", VERSION);
```

Is there any way to do that in Rust or do I have to write the same literal over and over again?

Comment: Take a look at `lazy_static`: https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/lazy-static.rs

Comment: @starblue Quoting from the README: "Using this macro, it is possible to have statics that require code to be executed at runtime in order to be initialized." In my example, no code should have to be executed at runtime.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since I was essentially trying to emulate C macros, I tried to solve the problem with Rust macros and succeeded:

```
macro_rules! description {
    () => ( "my program" )
}
macro_rules! version {
    () => ( env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION") )
}
macro_rules! version_string {
    () => ( concat!(description!(), " v", version!()) )
}
```

It feels a bit ugly to use macros instead of constants, but it works as expected.

Comment: See the answer that uses the [`const_format`](https://crates.io/crates/const_format) crate's `concatcp!()` macro.

Answer (score 17):

The compiler error is

> error: expected a literal

A literal is anything you type directly like `"hello"` or `5`. The moment you start working with constants, you are not using literals anymore, but identifiers. So right now the best you can do is

```
const VERSION_STRING: &'static str =
    concat!("my program v", env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION"));
```

Since the `env!` macro expands to a literal, you can use it inside `concat!`.

Comment: So, as I feared, I'll have to write the same literal over and over again.

Comment: You can always try to improve the `concat` macro to support constants ;) But it'll take a month or so until it's in stable rust

Comment: `concat` seems to be a compiler built-in: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/macros.rs#L311
I really don't want to patch the compiler ;)

Comment: You can still put up an issue in the issue tracker. It shouldn't be too much of a problem to allow simple constants in `concat!`

Comment: It will be a problem, since macros by definition can't know the value of constants (even the built-in ones), they run before the constants are evaluated and operate only on tokens.

Comment: What about making a built-in constant evaluation for creating a `&'static str` from other `&'static str`s?

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate named and literal constants of various types with the [`const_format`](https://crates.io/crates/const_format) crate.

This crate was available since August 2020, so this answer has only been possible to make in retrospect:

```rust
use const_format::concatcp;

const DESCRIPTION: &'static str = "my program";
const VERSION: &'static str = env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION");
const VERSION_STRING: &'static str = concatcp!(DESCRIPTION, " v", VERSION);
```

This macro even lets you concatenate number constants / literals into one `&'static str`.