# How to create a byte slice constant with specific value?

Tags: rust

How do I create a byte slice constant in rust, something as follows?

```rust
// This does not compile, but just to show my intention.
pub const MyConst: &'static [u8; 256] = b"abcdef" + [0u8; 250];

// Basically, the value is b"abcdef00000...", the `000...` appended at the end 
// are a series of byte 0, not character 0.
```

Comment: You can do this using const functions, or alternatively write the constant out by hand: `b"abcdef\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0..."`. More context would be helpful here as to why you need it.

Comment: I'm not sure that there are const functions that can work with `[u8; 256]`. I think you have to write this by hand. If it could be a `static` instead of a `const` then there are more options (like `lazy_static`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There currently isn't a feature in the language nor in the standard library for combining multiple byte arrays together into a single slice at compile time. There happens to be a [pending RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2509) proposing an extension to the `concat!` macro, which currently only works for string literals. There are no guarantees that it will ever be approved, though.

A few alternative solutions follow.

1. Make a UTF-8 string and call `as_bytes()`. As a string slice however, it won't be possible to include certain character combinations or write a compact representation of `[0u8; 250]`.

```rust
pub const BYTES: &[u8] = concat!("abcdef", "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0").as_bytes();
```

2. Some crates may claim to provide the solution that you are looking for. See [`proc_concat_bytes`](https://crates.io/crates/proc-concat-bytes), for example:

```rust
use proc_concat_bytes::concat_bytes;
let c_str  = &concat_bytes!(b"Hello World!", b'\0')[..]).unwrap();
```

3. Write the bytes to a file, then use `include_bytes!`.

```rust
const BYTES: &[u8; 258] = include_bytes!("bytes.bin");
```

4. Enter before-main land and construct a static vector with `lazy_static!`. We would then have a vector constructed by the program, but should fulfil the intended requirements once built.

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
    static ref BYTES: Vec<u8> = {
        let mut data = b"abcdefg".to_vec();
        data.extend(&[0u8; 250][..]);
        data
    };
}
```

See also:

- [How to concatenate static strings in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157399/how-to-concatenate-static-strings-in-rust)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `const fn` to create your array:

```rust
const fn foo() -> [u8; 256] {
    let mut a = [0; 256];
    a[0] = b'a';
    a[1] = b'b';
    a[2] = b'c';
    a[3] = b'd';
    a[4] = b'e';
    a[5] = b'f';
    a
}

const FOO: [u8; 256] = foo();

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", &FOO[0..10]);
}
```

Note that `const fn` are still pretty limited, so to my knowledge, you can't do any better than the sequence of `a[i] = b` at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

On recent nightly compilers, you can now use the [unstable `concat_bytes!` macro](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87555) to do this:

```rust
#![feature(concat_bytes)]
pub const MY_CONST: &[u8; 256] = concat_bytes!(b"abcdef", [0; 250]);
```